# xml interaction with php

Tags: php, xml

I'm new to these two languages! I'm trying to develop an website for a project I'm working on and I'm stuck. I have a picture in my webpage which is associated with a link. My code in xml is below
`<cover 
    img="images/metal_button2.jpg" 
    title="Add an new user"
    link="C:\wamp\www\project\modify_users1_l1.php" />`
However, the link opens in a new tab (which I don't want) and i cannot pass a variable to the php script that opens. Is there a way to click on the image and then set a value to a variable (which will be read by the php script via post method) and call a new php script?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`<cover />` is not a valid HTML element. So, if you are talking in terms of "clicking a link", then I infer that you have this piece of XML code rendered as proper "img" or "img" inside "a" element. So, I guess that this piece of XML you provided is rendered as:

```
<a href="C:\wamp\www\project\modify_users1_l1.php">
    <img src="images/metal_button2.jpg" />
    Add an new user <!-- note the orthographical error -->
</a>
```

You have to check inside Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, depending on your browser (hit F12).

You have a direct link to the file in your file system, which is wrong. You must call URLs in your website.

If you call URL on your PHP-based website, you can pass data to it by using the following syntax:

```
http://yourdomain.dom/modify_users1_l1.php?variable1_name=variable1_value&variable2_name=variable2_value
```

This is called a "request parameters", google it.

Inside the `modify_users1_l1.php` script you'll be able to get the passed value of `variable1_name` variable by reading `$_GET['variable1_name']`. Google for PHP "superglobal variables".

Also, being a n00b does not relieve you from RTM. PHP documentation is excellent, and you definitely should not use some XML transformed into PHP code without knowing what's going on.